# How to theme a list based field

Tags: entities, theming

I have a text field attached to my node.
The user can add an unlimited number of values.

I want to out put all the values as a HTML list in my node.tpl.php file.

Contemplate module suggests to use the following code to out put the field:

```
<?php print $node->field_body_list['und'][0]['safe_value'];?>
```

This, however, has two problems:
1) It only outputs the first value of the field.
2) It uses UND, which is [apparently bad](http://www.davereid.net/content/hlkd7fotw-field-get-items).

I have tried using theme developer, but it doesn't produce any code that I can use in my node.tpl.php file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to stay out of `node.tpl.php` for this one and instead use a field specific template file.

You'll need two copies of `/modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php` in your theme folder. The first is an exact duplicate with no changes and the same filename. The second you should rename to `field--field-body-list.tpl.php`. Consult [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) if that filename doesn't work for you.

In `field--field-body-list.tpl.php` I would change the div with `class="field-items"` to `<ul>` and the div with `class="field-item"` to `<li>`.